# how to extract values from a list?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs

first of all i have this kind of list which is filled like that:

```
        var data = {};
        liste_path_categories.forEach(function (element) {
        data[element.letter] = {};
        data[element.letter][element.id_categ] = element.reponse;
            });
```

So i checked if the list is filled or not:

```
       console.log("list data[][] to be send to the web service");
        for (var o in data) {
        for (var p in data[o]) {
            console.log("data[" + o + "][" + p + "]= " + data[o][p]);

        }
```

Everything is Ok .
Now when i append it to a FormData object to be in data for xhr post request:

```
      var mdata = new FormData();
    mdata.append('token', token);
    mdata.append('game_session_id', WinJS.Application.sessionState.game_session_id);
   /* mdata.append('data[A][6480]', "Affz");
    mdata.append('data[A][6483]', "Azfzf");
    mdata.append('data[A][6487]', "Azfz");
    mdata.append('data[A][6484]', "Afzf");
    mdata.append('data[A][6486]', "Azfzf");
    */
    mdata.append('data', data);
```

when i send i have a problem Internal server problem 
but when i comment that line  and send mdata.append(data by data in statiw way) in works and sent successfully.
What shoul i add to the data list , I tryied JSON.stringify(data) but it's fail .
If someone have an idea about how to extract all data and split the list data .
ANY HELP WILL be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So if manually appending yields the correct format, why don't you just

```
for key, subkeys of data
  for subkey, value of subkeys
    mdata.append("data[#{key}][#{subkey}]", value)
```